# WebClient - How to get source after you POST'ed something

Tags: c#, .net, webclient

I'm using WebClient with modified CookieAwareWebClient class.

How I want it to work: I log in using post, then go to search page where I post id of category and in return I want it to give me source of website that lists categories. I've managed to do that on Python and it is working fine, but on C# I think I'm doing something wrong here.

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
var client = new CookieAwareWebClient();
client.BaseAddress = @"http://site/";

// Logging in...
// This part works fine
var loginData = new NameValueCollection();
loginData.Add("login", "user");
loginData.Add("pass", "pass");
client.UploadValues("http://site/authorize.html", "POST", loginData);

// Searching for items
// Not so sure about this part since cannot read what is given back
var searchData = new NameValueCollection();
searchData.Add("catName", "tables");
client.UploadValues("http://site/search.html", "POST", searchData);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`WebClient.UploadValues`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9w7b4fz7.aspx) returns the response as a byte array, but you're currently ignoring that. Is that actually the data you want?

Comment: I didn't knew it returned array of bytes. Thanks, it works now!

Comment: @Qmal: Neither did I before I looked up the documentation ;)

Comment: @JonSkeet how is that possible 8| ?